# How do I check if a Global field exists in a template?

Tags: templating, globals

In a template, can I check whether a Global field exists, before I try to output its value? I want to ensure the page doesn't break entirely in the unlikely event of the field being removed from the CMS.

If I do:

```
{% if myGlobalSet.myField is defined %}
    Defined.
{% endif %}
```

then it works as expected; "Defined" isn't displayed if `myField` doesn't exist.

But if I have:

```
{% if myGlobalSet.myField is defined %}
    Defined. {{ myGlobalSet.myField }}
{% endif %}
```

I get:

> Craft\GlobalSetModel and its behaviours do not have a method or closure named "myField".

if that field doesn't exist. It's like it's trying to process the field even though it's not defined.

Answer (score 1):

That's a known issue with Twig's `is defined` test.  See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2117/57) for an explanation and workarounds.

Note that this is no longer an issue in the upcoming Craft 3.

Comment: Ah, thanks Brad. How do I use that workaround with a global rather than an entry though? `myGlobalSet.type` and `myGlobalSet.myField.type` both generate errors.

Comment: Ahh, good point. Let me think on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`BaseModel::getAttribute()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#getFieldValue-detail):

```
{% if myGlobalSet.getAttribute('myField') %}
    Defined.
{% else %}
    Not defined.
{% endif %}
```

I was going to suggest [`BaseElementModel::getFieldValue()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#getFieldValue-detail) as the "proper" way, but that throws an exception if the field isn't found *at all*, so I think `getAttribute()` is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that I still get the same error.