# Accessing array/object attributes in Twig

Tags: templating

There are three methods for that:

```
object.attribute
```

```
object['attribute']
```

```
attr(object, 'attribute')
```

How are these different from each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    {{ entry.title }}
```

compiles down to:

```php
        echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, craft\helpers\Template::attribute($this->env, $this->source, (isset($context["entry"]) || array_key_exists("entry", $context) ? $context["entry"] : (function () { throw new RuntimeError('Variable "entry" does not exist.', 19, $this->source); })()), "title", []), "html", null, true);
```

...and

```
    {{ entry['title'] }}
```

compiles down to:

```php
        echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, craft\helpers\Template::attribute($this->env, $this->source, (isset($context["entry"]) || array_key_exists("entry", $context) ? $context["entry"] : (function () { throw new RuntimeError('Variable "entry" does not exist.', 20, $this->source); })()), "title"), "html", null, true);
```

...and

```
    {{ attribute(entry, 'title') }}
```

compiles down to:

```php
        echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, craft\helpers\Template::attribute($this->env, $this->source, (isset($context["entry"]) || array_key_exists("entry", $context) ? $context["entry"] : (function () { throw new RuntimeError('Variable "entry" does not exist.', 21, $this->source); })()), "title", [], "array"), "html", null, true);
```

If they look similar, that's because... they are identical in terms of the PHP code they compile down to.

So the difference is... whichever one uses the fewest keystrokes to type.

Comment: There seems to hovewer be some difference - for non existing field, `entry.dwfgfrg is defined` returns true, but `entry['dwfgfrg'] is defined` returns false.

Comment: Check out Ben Parizek's answer in this thread: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/twig-is-defined-always-returning-true

Comment: They will definitely throw different errors in different circumstances. You may want to conduct the same test, but where `entry` is properly defined, and it's only the `attribute` that is missing.

Comment: The difference here is in how the "is defined" test works tho, now how the various ways of accessing properties works. Ben gives a really good explanation in the above link